# Shopify having trouble adding an additional style sheet in older prestige theme

Tags: shopify, liquid

Hi thanks for having a look. I am having trouble adding an additional stylesheet to older prestige theme for whatever reason it’s not getting recognized.

I am adding it in theme.liquid like this {{ 'application.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

NOTE The file has same name in assets directory, and if I put in the product section it works.

See screenshot I tried it above or below.

This works fine for me in the dawn theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on for some reason when I add the stylesheet tag in my local dev environment it does not carry over to theme code.

So when I added it directly in theme code editor it worked fine.

So I did it like this:

```
        {{ 'application.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your syntax (apostrophes). Also, ensure that application.css actually exists in the /assets directory

`{{ 'application.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}`

not:

`{{ ‘application.css’ | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}`

Comment: Thanks for having a look. The quotes were not an issue, it was just formatting in the question that i fixed.. See the Image.